# Медленно прогружаются картинки на сайте

Tags: hibernate, java-ee, spring-mvc, изображения

Сделал web application на java ee spring + hibernate.
На локальном компьютере картинки грузились считанные секунды.
Как только залил на VDS возникла проблема. Картинки стали грузиться в 10 раз дольше. И чтобы ждать прогрузки фоновой картинки уходят ЧАСЫ...

1. В чем может быть причина подскажите пожалуйста?
2. Может нужно применять какие-либо сжатие на картинки?
3. У меня оперативная память на VDS 1 GB RAM. Может не хватает RAM?

Вот сервлет который читает картинку:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/image/accaunt", method = {RequestMethod.GET})
    @ResponseBody
    public byte[] getImageAccaunt(
        @ModelAttribute(SessionAttr.ACCAUNT) Accaunt accaunt,
        Authentication authentication
    )  {
        User user = authentication!=null && authentication.isAuthenticated()?accaunt.getUser():null;

        if (user!=null && user.getPhoto()!=null) {
            return user.getPhoto();
        } else {
            String pathNull = "/WEB-INF/resources/img/profile_null.png";
            try {
                return IOUtils.toByteArray(servletContext.getResourceAsStream(pathNull));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

UPDT:
вот F12
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPDT:
вот RAM

```
MemTotal:        1009172 kB
MemFree:          123044 kB
MemAvailable:     188316 kB
Buffers:            6380 kB
Cached:           180288 kB
SwapCached:         1064 kB
Active:           523244 kB
Inactive:         318700 kB
Active(anon):     447612 kB
Inactive(anon):   207932 kB
Active(file):      75632 kB
Inactive(file):   110768 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:         85368 kB
SwapFree:          58220 kB
Dirty:                12 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:        654432 kB
Mapped:            30404 kB
Shmem:               248 kB
Slab:              23852 kB
SReclaimable:      12836 kB
SUnreclaim:        11016 kB
KernelStack:        2720 kB
PageTables:         4816 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:      589952 kB
Committed_AS:    1175384 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:           0 kB
VmallocChunk:          0 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
ShmemPmdMapped:        0 kB
CmaTotal:              0 kB
CmaFree:               0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:       53236 kB
DirectMap2M:      995328 kB
```

Comment: А сколько весит фоновая картинка? Какая скорость скачивания? Может ли быть что у вас канал забит или сильно ограничен? Картинки png/jpg/<и т.п.> и так сжатые

Comment: у вас VDS на какой оси? Если грешите на Ram, дак проверьте хватает ли её

Comment: @alex сейчс проверю

Comment: @gil9red обновил вопрос

Comment: ого. С таким весом картинок о быстродействии и речи быть не может

Comment: @alex обновил по памяти RAM

Comment: @alex VDS брал потестить. Ubuntu 18.04 CPU: 1 core   RAM: 1 Гб   SSD: 30 Гб   Трафик: 2 Тб

Comment: Вы грузите примерно 115 мб. картинок на страницу. Может ограничена скорость интернета на хостинге, может не хватает на клиенте. Даже если у вас 100мбит/сек, то чисто на загрузку надо секунд 10 + плюс рендеринг

Comment: @alex насколько я понял необходимо поработать над уменьшением веса картинок?

Comment: да. сжимайте картинки